# Windows Shell and Citrix

Tags: delphi, winapi, citrix

I have this line of code in my Delphi app:

```
sh := CoShellWindows.Create;
```

When run through a Citrix session, this raises an exception "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation."

Can someone confirm my suspicion that I can't access this through Citrix?  I'm running in Seamless mode if that makes any difference.  Maybe there's something I need to change on the published icon to make it work?

I am guessing that there is no "Shell" in Citrix to create.

Thanks

**EDIT**

The [CoShellWindows](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SHDocVw.CoShellWindows) is simply a class which creates an object which implements the [IShellWindows interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  This interface is then used to iterate through it's items looking for an instance of Internet Explorer (or more specifically, an item which implements the IWebBrowser2 interface).

There are a few other use case scenarios using the CoShellWindows, but all ultimately are used to interact with the IWebBrowser2 interface (Internet Explorer 8).  My requirement is to obtain this IWebBrowser2 object.

The call, behind the scenes is calling the Windows API CoCreateInstance with the following parameters:

- rclsid = {9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39} (CLSID of
  IShellWindows)
- pUnkOuter = null (nil)
- dwClsContext = CLSCTX_ALL (I've tried various combinations of these
  flags)
- riid = {85CB6900-4D95-11CF-960C-0080C7F4EE85} (IID of IShellWindows)
- ppv = a    variable declared as type IShellWindows

eg:CoCreateInstance(CLASS_ShellWindows, nil, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IShellWindows, sh)

Comment: I might help you but I know nothing about Delphi - what is CoShellWindows.Create supposed to do? Remember that with a published application there is no shell (i.e. desktop).

Comment: I don't know what this CoShell thing is, but I can confirm that you CAN run external .bat and .exe programs from your main app. We've got a Delphi app that runs from the Citrix icon, and it runs lots of reports which are all external .exe programs.

Answer (score 4):

Your exception "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation." should really read "Shell does not exist so no instance can be created"

Basically you are correct in your assumption that there is no shell to create in Citrix.

What are you using the shell for? as if you provide more information we may well be able to offer a full work around.